# Expressing an age differently

Tags: word-choice, aspect

I normally know 2 different versions of pointing an age of a person as follows:

> She will **be** 12 years old in July.
>
> She will **turn** 12 in July.

I wonder that is there any other positions in order to point an age except the above structures?

**Edit**: Actually, this might be too board but I just wanted the closest ones of such statements.

Comment: If you want to speak of someone's age imprecisely, you can use phrases such as: "He is a twenty-something.", "She is 16 going (on) 17."

Comment: Is your question, "How many different ways can we express the idea that she will be 12 in July?" She'll celebrate her twelfth birthday in July.  July will mark the 12th anniversary of her birth, In July she'll have been around the Sun 12 times... I think this is too open ended.

Comment: Also,"She's getting on for 50."= He's reaching the age of 50.

Comment: If someone said that "she's getting on for 50", I would understand that to mean that she looks or acts as if she is actually quite a bit older than 50, even though 50 is her true age.  This may be a regionalism, though.  (either US Midwest or East Coast.)

Comment: Yeah I agree with @Hellion. I think Vic might have meant "She's going on 50", which does mean "she's approaching the age of 50".

Comment: Then there's the possibility of saying it in the negative: _She won't turn 12 until July._ That might be most natural in some contexts, such as: "Is your daughter 12?" Answer: "No, she's only 11. She won't turn 12 until July."

Comment: "be getting on for" means to be nearly a particular time, age, or number. Example: "It must be getting on for midnight", "Vic is getting on for 50."

Comment: @Vic- I believe that's "getting on *towards*".  It's getting on *towards* midnight.

Answer (score 1):

The most common ones in American English, for describing a birthday that hasn't yet arrived, would be:

> She turns 12 in July
>
> She will be 12 in July
>
> She will turn 12 in July
>
> She will be turning 12 in July
>
> She's going to be 12 in July
>
> She's going to turn 12 in July
>
> She's going to be turning 12 in July

This is because you get your choice of two future tense markings ("will" or "is going to"), two aspects (simple or continuous) and two different verbs ("to be") or ("to turn").

However, be aware that "be" and "turn" have slightly different meanings in this context. "To turn" unambiguously refers to her birthday; "to be" does not. So, for example, you could say:

> You have to be 12 to join, and she's only 11. But it should be okay, because her birthday is in May, so **she will be 12 in July,** when the course starts.

You could not use "turn" in the boldfaced portion of that sentence. However, you're correct that when used on its own, without a surrounding context, "will be 12 in July" strongly suggests that her birthday will be in July.

You can also, of course, use a large number of other expressions to express the same idea:

> Her twelfth birthday will be in July
>
> July will be her twelfth birthday
>
> She'll be eleven until July

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This is used especially in Britain: *be getting on for* = to be nearly a particular age. For example: "He's getting on for 80."